# How I can get the file id after upload a file to google drive?

Tags: cocoa, google-drive-api

I want to know the file id after upload. find it from file list, I think that isn't good idea and performance. so, How I can get the file id with good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) you get the id from the response, eg `File file = request.ResponseBody;Msgbox(file.Id)`

Comment: I got it in response body, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($fileTitle);
$result = $service->files->create(
    $file,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents(FILE),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    )
);
```

Var $result contain all information about uploaded file,so all you have to do is to display or use id.

```
echo 'Uploaded file id is '.$result['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone coming from **.Net** background, use:

```cs
string fileId = request.ResponseBody.Id;
```

To get download link also, remember to set

```cs
request. Fields = "id, webContentLink";
string fileId = request.ResponseBody.Id;
string downloadLink = request.ResponseBody.WebContentLink;
```

In order to get download link you will need to set shared permission to the uploaded file **after uploading the file**.

```cs
var permission = new Permission { AllowFileDiscovery = true, Type = "anyone", Role = "reader" };
await driveService.Permissions.Create(permission, request.ResponseBody.Id).ExecuteAsync();
```